# Drawing Images at Random Positions Without Touching

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I think picture will be better example than words

When I use random number I get incorrect result

[image: Current Version]

but I want get this result:

[image: Rectified Version]

I found something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var containerW = 700;
    var containerH = 600;
    var positions = [];
    $('.picture').each(function() {
        var coords = {
            w: $(this).outerWidth(true),
            h: $(this).outerHeight(true)
        };
        var success = false;
        while (!success)
        {
            coords.x = parseInt(Math.random() * (containerW-coords.w));
            coords.y = parseInt(Math.random() * (containerH-coords.h));
            var success = true;
            $.each(positions, function(){
                if (
                    coords.x <= (this.x + this.w) &&
                    (coords.x + coords.w) >= this.x &&
                    coords.y <= (this.y + this.h) &&
                    (coords.y + coords.h) >= this.y
                )
                {
                    success = false;
                }
            });
        }
        positions.push(coords);
        $(this).css({
            top: coords.y + 'px',
            left: coords.x + 'px'
        });
    });
});
```

How can I improve this?

Comment: Please provide your code so that we can help you explicitly. However, by the looks of it I can tell that it is the maths that is wrong in the program.

Remember that you specify left-top corner coordinates of the canvas. You might want to display the picture in the center of the point by subtracting half with and height of width and height of the picture respectively.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler as well as faster approach is to use a grid constraint where each cell is a bit larger than the shape. Then randomly place a shape within each single cell.

The only limitation here is that the shapes are bound to a certain structure as the shapes will never move into the surround areas.

### Example of grid solution

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
    cellsX = 10,
    cellsY = 5,
    cellW = c.width / cellsX,
    cellH = c.height / cellsY,
    padding = 2,           // minimum space between each shape
    shapeMaxW = cellW>>1,  // these shape sizes are just arbitrary
    shapeMaxH = cellH>>1;

function render() {
  c.width = c.width;
  for(var i = 0; i < cellsX * cellsY; i++) {
    var x = ((cellW - padding) - shapeMaxW) * Math.random() +  (i % cellsX)    * cellW;
    var y = ((cellH - padding) - shapeMaxH) * Math.random() + ((i / cellsX)|0) * cellH;
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, shapeMaxW, shapeMaxH);
  }
}

setInterval(render, 200); // demo loop
```

```html
<canvas id=c width=600 height=200></canvas>
```